# Dealing with .htaccess RewriteEngine and subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This might be a duplicate question but I couldn't really find a good explanation to the problem that I'm dealing with. Here it is:

Objective 1 [Works fine]: To write a rule that takes the users to a url without www
eg.: user type www.myurl.com  ->  output on address bay: myurl.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myurl.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myurl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Objective 2 [Can get it to work :(]: To write a rule that take the users that visit a subdomain url with www to the same address without www. 
eg.: user type www.subdomain.myurl.com -> output on address bar: subdomain.myurl.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.*.myurl.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://*.myurl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The output for the second example if the user type www.subdomain.myurl.com is coming out as http://*.myurl.com/subdomain/ instead of subdomain.myrul.com .

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.myurl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's working better then what I had, but now if I type www.subdomain.myurl.com it returns subdomain.myurl.com/subdomain/ . I'm playing with it to see if I get it working, but any help is welcome.